# preventDefault() is not working

Tags: jquery

My Goal is to remove the action of checkbox checking by clicking on its label
Below is my code..

```
   $('TABLE TBODY TR TD').each(function()
   {
     $(this).find('input').each(function()
                            {
                                $('label for='+$(this)+'').preventDefault();
                            });
    });
```

Below is the associated HTML..

```
  <table>
        <tr><input type="checkbox" id="a1"><div><label for="a1">ClickMe</lable></div></tr>
  </table>
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preventDefault` is not a method on the jQuery object itself. It is a method on the event that gets passed to a given event handler.

In addition, your label selector syntax is wrong (you forgot brackets and tried to concatenate a jQuery object with a string), and you have unnecessarily nested two `each`es.

Better:

```
$("table tbody tr td input").each(function () {
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9D4n/

Possibly even simpler, but admittedly not functionally equivalent:

```
$("label").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: "not working"!! The best description of what went wrong... ever. Can you describe what's not working, and maybe produce a JSFiddle example of it not working? Because the JSFiddle I linked to in my post shows that it works. (I had to correct your invalid HTML though...)

Comment: @Pranthap your HTML is invalid; you have no `<td>` inside your `<tr>`, no `<tbody>` inside your `<table>`, your `<label>` closing tag is misspelled, and you have a `</label>` instead of a `</table>`. All these cause the selector to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `for` attribute from the label.

```
<label>ClickMe</label>
```